# Initialize react hook in a class based component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am trying to change the function-based component to the class-based component.  I am getting an error while converting.  How to initialize hook in a class component.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOQ8.png)

Papebase Material UI

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Navigator from '../Components/Navigator';
import Content from './Content';
import Header from '../Components/Header';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Link as RouteLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Podo
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

let theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#63ccff',
      main: '#009be5',
      dark: '#006db3',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    h5: {
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: 26,
      letterSpacing: 0.5,
    },
  },
  shape: {
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  props: {
    MuiTab: {
      disableRipple: true,
    },
  },
  mixins: {
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: 48,
    },
  },
});

theme = {
  ...theme,
  overrides: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      paper: {
        backgroundColor: '#18202c',
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      label: {
        textTransform: 'none',
      },
      contained: {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        '&:active': {
          boxShadow: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
    MuiTabs: {
      root: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      },
      indicator: {
        height: 3,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 3,
        borderTopRightRadius: 3,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      },
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        textTransform: 'none',
        margin: '0 16px',
        minWidth: 0,
        padding: 0,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
          padding: 0,
          minWidth: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
      },
    },
    MuiTooltip: {
      tooltip: {
        borderRadius: 4,
      },
    },
    MuiDivider: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#404854',
      },
    },
    MuiListItemText: {
      primary: {
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
      },
    },
    MuiListItemIcon: {
      root: {
        color: 'inherit',
        marginRight: 0,
        '& svg': {
          fontSize: 20,
        },
      },
    },
    MuiAvatar: {
      root: {
        width: 32,
        height: 32,
      },
    },
  },
};

const drawerWidth = 256;

const styles = {
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    minHeight: '100vh',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  app: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(6, 4),
    background: '#eaeff1',
  },
  footer: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    background: '#eaeff1',
  },
};





export class Paperbase extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
      setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
    };
    return (

      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <nav className={classes.drawer}>
              <Hidden smUp implementation="js">
                <Navigator
                  PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }}
                  variant="temporary"
                  open={mobileOpen}
                  onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
                />
              </Hidden>
              <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                <Navigator PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }} />
              </Hidden>
            </nav>
            <div className={classes.app}>
              <Header onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} />
              <main className={classes.main}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard/auth" render={() => <Content /> } />
                <Route path="/Inbox" render={() => <div> Page inbox</div>} />
                <Route path="/Starred" render={() => <div>PSage starred</div>} />
              </Switch>
              </main>
              <footer className={classes.footer}>
                <Copyright />
              </footer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}


Paperbase.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


export default withStyles(styles)(Paperbase);
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class
This will show you how to change it completely. You have to do more than rename the function to a class, but not **much** more!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer you can't use react hooks on class based components.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly longer answer:

Hooks were introduced to allow use of state in function components. If you're using a class component, then the mechanisms to manipulate state are built into the default class component behavior.

So in your example, you'd want to do something like:

Replace your state hook:

```js
const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
      setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
    };
```

with a stateful class component and `setState()`:

```js
class PaperBase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       mobileOpen: true,
         }
      this.handleDrawerToggle = this.handleDrawerToggle.bind(this);
      }

       handleDrawerToggle = () => {
       let mobileOpen = this.state.mobileOpen;
       mobileOpen != mobileOpen;
       this.setState = {
           mobileOpen: mobileOpen, 
      }

   }
         // ...
}
```

Rather than explain how it all works here, I'll suggest reading the official tutorial on state in components: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html